# Add Search and sort function to data binding wrapper

Tags: c#, data-binding, arcgis, arcobjects

I'm using a C# [wrapper of ITable object (ESRI ArcObject Table)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Sample_Bind_a_geodatabase_table_to_a_NET_control/000100000312000000/), but this wrapper misses sorting and searching functions. Is there a way to add these functions? How could I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two ways to attempt this. Both require that you create a new class that is derived from `TableWrapper`.

**1.** The first option is to simply expose the `Items` property of TableWrapper (inherited from `BindingList<IRow>`). Once you have done that, you can use `System.Linq` to get a sorted version of the items, or search the items. This might **not** work for your scenario, if you need to listen for the ListChanged event.

```
public class GeoGeekTable : TableWrapper 
{
    public IList<IRow> GetTableItems()
    {
        return this.Items;
    } 
}
```

**2.** The longer route is to provide a more complete implementation of `BindingList<T>` by creating a class that inherits from `TableWrapper` and implements the inherited methods that are missing in `TableWrapper`.

`BindingList<T>` defines these methods:

> **ApplySortCore**: Sorts the items if overridden in a derived class; otherwise, throws a
>   NotSupportedException.
>
> **FindCore** : Searches for the index of the item that has the specified property descriptor with the specified value, if searching
>   is implemented in a derived class; otherwise, a NotSupportedException.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132690.aspx

```
public class GeoGeekTable : TableWrapper
{
    protected override void ApplySortCore(PropertyDescriptor prop, ListSortDirection direction)
    {
        // see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/22693b0e-8637-4734-973e-abbc72065969/
    }
}
```

I hope that helps get you started. If you search "override ApplySortCore c#" you should get some guidance on implementing that method, as it's standard .NET

Comment: Thanks for your Response, i would prefere  the second way that's already implemented in wrapper that i mentioned in the link, but what i want is to avoid the NotSupportedException, because both sort and search are not supported in ITable, i thought to add these functions to the wrapper, how i could do it if possible ?  Thanks

Comment: If you have the source code for the wrapper you could alter it and add the overrides, but I think it's better to extend a class if it's part of an external library. Instead of deriving a class from ITable, derive it from TableWrapper.